# Getting 400 Error When Uploading PDF File

Tags: reactjs, flask

I want to upload pdf file from react to flask db. However, I am getting 400 error when uploading the pdf file and I don't know why.
React code:

```
 var formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('report', pdf)
      formData.append('id', user_id)
      formData.append('title', x)

fetch('/upReport', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
       }
      }).then(res => res.json()).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
```

Flask code:

```
@app.route("/upReport", methods=["POST"])
def report():
    if 'report' not in request.files:
        resp = jsonify({'message' : 'No file part in the request'})
        resp.status_code = 400
        return resp

    report = request.files["report"]
    user_id= request.form.get("id")
    title= request.form.get("title")
    newReport = Report(title=title, data=report.read(), user_id=user_id)
    db.session.add(newReport)
    db.session.commit()
    return {"success": 200}
```

In the console I got 400 error and says: "'message' : 'No file part in the request'"

Comment: Check if you have anything in request.files (you can simply print it to console)

Comment: It doesnt print anything

Comment: Would you not also retrieve the contents of 'report' via `request.form.get('report')`? So can you check if the 'report' key is found in `request.form` instead of `request.files`?

Comment: Same error occurred :(

Comment: After removing the definition of the `headers` in the `fetch` statement, it worked for me.

Comment: No it didnt work :/

Comment: @BeyzaYıldırım Is there any feedback in the console or in the terminal? Or is the result still the same?

Comment: It is still the same error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST). I have no idea why I keep getting this. I did almost everything to fix but...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on react, but the following example is based on your code and works.
I have essentially removed the header information in the ajax request. It is set automatically.
It may help you further to fix the problem in your code even though I used the sources from the CDN.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    if 'report' not in request.files:
        return jsonify(message='No file part in the request'), 400

    report = request.files['report']
    user_id = request.form.get('id')
    title = request.form.get('title')

    # ...
    print(user_id, title, report)

    return jsonify(message='Success'), 200
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="upload-form"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      'use strict';

      class UploadForm extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            report: null,
          };
          this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
          this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }

        handleSubmit(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("report", this.state.report);
          formData.append("id", 20);
          formData.append("title", "Untitled File");

          fetch(
            "/upload",
            {
              method: "POST",
              body: formData,
            }
          )
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
        }

        handleChange(event) {
          const target = event.target;
          const key = target.name;
          const val = target.files[0];
          this.setState({[key]: val});
        }

        render() {
          return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <input name="report" type="file" onChange={this.handleChange} />
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          );
        }
      }

      const e = React.createElement;
      ReactDOM.render(
        e(UploadForm),
        document.querySelector('#upload-form')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this, it didn't give any error so I thought it worked for a moment. But db didn't save any report. But thanks for your time!

Comment: @BeyzaYıldırım No problem. Hope it brings you closer to your goal. If an error occurs when saving in the database, it should be recognizable in the command line. Have fun.